# local variable 'product' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a django view which will let users to create a new product on the website.

```
class CreateProductView(APIView):
    serializer_class = CreateProductSerializer

    def post(self, request, format = None):
        

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.data.name
            content = serializer.data.content
            category = serializer.data.category

            product = Product(name=name, content=content, category=category)
            product.save()

        return Response(ProductSerializer(product).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

But it is giving this error:

```
UnboundLocalError at /api/create-product
local variable 'product' referenced before assignment
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-product
Django Version: 4.0.5
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    
local variable 'product' referenced before assignment
Exception Location: H:\Extension Drive (H)\My Software Applications\DeCluttered_Life\declutterd_life\api\views.py, line 42, in post
Python Executable:  C:\Python310\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.5
Python Path:    
['H:\\Extension Drive (H)\\My Software '
 'Applications\\DeCluttered_Life\\declutterd_life',
 'C:\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Python310',
 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 02 Dec 2022 17:26:24 +0000
```

I tried to look other issues similar to this, but couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference the product variable before it has been assigned when `serializer.is_valid()` is False.

You should move the response line inside the if statement, so that it is only returned if serializer.is_valid() is True and handle the response for invalid serializer with an http error for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I moved the response line inside the if statement, but now it is showing another error: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

Comment: Yes, the error is quite explicit, you are not returning anything in that case and the view is expected to return a HttpResponse. Return an HttpResponse when the serializer is invalid. I suggest you to read the documentation on views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/views/

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `serializer.is_valid()` returns `True`. If it doesn't, your code attempts to return a `Response` object, which uses the `product` variable. However, if your `serializer.is_valid()` does returns `False`, the `Response` is still created with the `product` variable, which has not been created yet.

It might be wise to write functionality that handles the situation when your `serializer.is_valid()` returns `False`. In that case, probably you don't need the `product` variable.